# SSHPASS in shell_exec PHP

Tags: php, shell-exec, sshpass

I have a small problem with shell_exec.
I'm currently trying to get a list of files or directorys on a remote Linux Server. The server, directory and the password which is necessaria to login I catch over a formular.

Here the command which should be executed on the server:

```
$x = "sshpass -p \"$pwd\" ssh root@$server \"ls $ordner\"";
$x = shell_exec('$x');
var_dump ($x);
```

When I dump $x before I send it trough the shell_exec the command seems fine and works directly in the shell. As soon as it runs trough the shell_exec command the only feedback I get from var_dump is NULL.

I would be very grateful if somebody can help me with my problem. Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use the SSH2 extension or phpseclib? (you pobably need to provide the full path to sshpass and check its permissions)

Comment: Ok, you helped me a lot. Thanks.
First i need to install libssh2-php and now it works great with your help with SSH2 :)